# Asp.net Login status not saying logout after user logs in

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a asp.net web application, that allows users to login and logout. When a user logs in (no problem) its says Welcome Username, which is fine. But next to it still says login. Can anyone help me is there some property i need to set on Logged in? Thanks for any help.

```
<asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                    <AnonymousTemplate>
                        [ <a href="~/Account/Login.aspx" id="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a>
                        ]
                    </AnonymousTemplate>
                    <LoggedInTemplate>
                        <span class="bold">Welcome</span><span class="bold">
                            <asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" />
                        </span>! [
                        <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out"
                            LogoutPageUrl="~/" />
                        ]
                    </LoggedInTemplate>
                </asp:LoginView>

protected void LoginUser_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
       SqlHelper userLogin = new SqlHelper();
        TextBox User = (TextBox) LoginUser.FindControl("UserName");
        TextBox Password = (TextBox) LoginUser.FindControl("Password");
        bool results = userLogin.UserLogin(User.Text, Password.Text);
        e.Authenticated = results;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two controls with an ID of HeadLoginStatus. Is there a reason for that? Secondly, have you tried removing EnableViewState="false"?

**EDIT**

Try changing the startup page to a page in the root directory, if it's not already. See if this makes any difference.

> I seemed to have found the problem..or a solution depending on how you
>   view it.
>
> I had my startup page set to a page in a sub directory and not in the
>   root. I changed the startup page to be a page in the root (which is
>   where login.aspx exists) and now it works as expected. I do not think
>   it should have acted like this though.

Comment: I did not touch anything that is the default setting that visual studio provided.

Comment: Can you try changing the two things I mentioned and see if it makes any difference?

Comment: Tried them both and still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

still not sure why its not authenticating but I found a work around that works 
when they click the sign out (I had to change the sign in to say sign out on loginstatus) do this

```
if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
          FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
          Session.Abandon();
          // clear authentication cookie
          HttpCookie cookie1 = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "");
          cookie1.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
          Response.Cookies.Add(cookie1);
          // clear session cookie (not necessary for your current problem but i would recommend you do it anyway)
          HttpCookie cookie2 = new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", "");
          cookie2.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
          Response.Cookies.Add(cookie2);

         Response.Redirect("~/");
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove Anynymoustemplate. Never heard about it. It should not be there.

```
<AnonymousTemplate>
 [ <a href="~/Account/Login.aspx" id="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a>
 ]
 </AnonymousTemplate>
```

Edit: Sorry I goofed. For some reasons, you anonymous template is still showing after they are logged in.

Comment: This needs to be there so users that are not logged in can see it.

Comment: Anonymous template: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview.anonymoustemplate.aspx

Comment: Thats not the problem, I added text to test to see if this was the issue and its not.